# if $k(p,n) := \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor$, then $\prod_{p \leq n} p^{k(p,n)}$ divides $n!$

Tags: number-theory

I was reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029640/sum-p-in-mathcal-p-frac1p-ln-p-converges-or-diverges) article about the convergence of the series $\sum_p \frac{1}{p\cdot log(p)}$. The second comment uses a weaker version of Merten's First Theorems, but a got lost on the formula described as in the title of this question.

> For each prime $p⩽n$, there are $k(p,n) := \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor$ multiples of $p$ that are $⩽n$, and hence $\prod_{p⩽n} p^{k(p,n)} ∣ n!$

I understood the account of the multiples of $p$. But, I can't understand the productory dividing $n!$ I appreciate any help :D

Comment: If there are $m$ multiples of $p$ in $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$, then their product $n!$ must contain at least $m$ times the factor $p$, so at least the factor $p^m$

Comment: @wasn'tme you're not helping

Comment: Sorry, I can't. You proved yourself that $p^m|n!$, and your $m$ is exactly $k(p,n)$. That's all, there isn't more to it.

Comment: ok, so $p^{k(n,p)}$ divides $n!$. What about the others $p \leq n$ on the productory?

Comment: The reasoning above works for every $p$ prime less than $n$, so it must hold also for their product